# How do I use a function argument for this jquery code, or is there a better solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 50 p tags and next to these are again 50 divs. on click of each p tag, its div should be shown and the rest hidden. How do i acheive this. I can use something like below:

```
$(function() {
  $('.p1').click(function(){
  $('.div1').show();
  $('.div2','.div3','.div4','.div5','.div6',.........,'.div50').hide()
})
$('.p2').click(function(){
  $('.div2').show();
  $('.div1','.div3','.div4','.div5','.div6',.........,'.div50').hide()
})
//////////////
//////
})
```

but as you see that this is not an effiecient solution. I am also not sure how the jquery `each` can be leveraged here or how can this implementation be done using arrays. Can somebody point me in the right direction. I think we should use a function and pass that no. as a parameter, but I dont know how to use custom functions in jquery.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have done

```
$(function() {
        $('.p1').click(function() {
            $('.div').hide();
            $('.d1').show();
        })
    })
```

I have added the class div to all of my 50 divs and I am showing d1 on click of p1. Now how do I replace 1 for each instance till 50.

Comment: Could you provide a small, representative example of the markup?

Comment: I think your HTML markup is wrong if you need this.

Comment: @MattBall My page has a lots of p's and div's apart from that, The p's and divs' I am working on have classes as p1,p2....p50 and divs as div1, div2, div3....div50. and there is other markup in between, so the question of using next() doesn't arise

Comment: I am just wondering cant we take the no. 1 from class of p and show the corresponding div that has also class ending with 1

Comment: Can you check my answer ? I think, I am doing what you want. Taking the no from your `p` and using that no to show only that `div`.

Comment: @Jashwant Thanks for your answer, but it didnt work can you put a fiddle for me as I am unable to understand it.

Comment: @Mike Added the fiddle link to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have a common class to all `div` and `p` so that the binding the handler and the `hide` can be simple. And for the div, I would associate a data-tag to each `p` to link each `p` tag to `div`

```
<p class="p1 pclass" data-showdiv="div1">
 ...
</p>
<p class="p2 pclass" data-showdiv="div2">
..

<div class="mydiv div1" ..>
..
</div>
<div class="mydiv div2" ..>
..
</div>
```

And the script would be,

```
$(function() {
  $('.pclass').click(function(){
     $('.mydiv').hide();
     $('.' + $(this).data('showdiv')).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: @Mike a way to associate some data to DOM element which can be later read using [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) jQuery function. [Read more...](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/)

Comment: @Mike Did you try to check out my suggestion?

Comment: Off-course it did work, but I just want to learn how to get those ending digits of p and div and get it to work.

Comment: And btw this will also not work in IE, so I need to think for IE also

Comment: @Mike And why would it not work in IE, I can run a quick test.. but do you know why?

Comment: I am also confused, may be this is html5 feature and IE is ignoring it. I am checking on IE8

Comment: DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RTxGf/ << Tested in IE 7 and FF 12. Let me know how it goes in IE 8. click on the para tag that says 'Show div 1'..

Comment: actually  something is wrong in my ie, i re-installed it and still some pieces wont work. guess its firebug or debug bar. anyways 
+1 added and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason told,

Use this

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $(this).next('div').show();
});
```

If the `div` is next to each paragraph.

But, if there's an element between `p` and `div`, it wont work.

For you problem, you can do,

```
$('p').click(function() {
        $('div').hide();
        var divClass = $(this).attr("class").replace('p','div');
        $('.' + divClass).show();
    });
```

provided you have only `p1`, `p2` .... in paragrah classes ;)

**Update**

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA6Ak/1/)

Notice , we have `<br>` tags between `<p>` and `<div>` as you wanted.

Comment: I have first fifty p's spread into 2 coloums(25 each) and then a bottom div that holds 50 divs. Like how vega has in his fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML structure is

```
<p>Some text</p>
<div>More text to hide and show</div>
<p>Some text</p>
<div>More text to hide and show</div>
<p>Some text</p>
<div>More text to hide and show</div>
....
```

Use the following in your `$(function(){});` method:

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $(this).next('div').show();
});
```

Comment: My page has a lots of p's and div's apart from that, The p's and divs' I am working on have classes as p1,p2....p50 and divs as div1, div2, div3....div50. and there is other markup in between so next() wont work.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid, but my markup has first 50 ps'and then some more mark up and then 50 divs. meaning it is difficult to use next() and closest()

Comment: I am just wondering cant we take the no. 1 from class of p and show the corresponding div that has also class ending with 1

Answer (score 0):

```
var dvs = ['.div1','.div2','.div3','.div4','.div5','.div6',.........,'.div50'];

$('p').click(function() {
    var index = parseInt(this.className.replace('p','')) - 1;
    $(dvs[index]).show();
    $(dvs.join(', ')).not(dvs[index]).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `click` event will automatically be registered on all elements that match the selector, so you shouldn't have to use the `each()` method. I would suggest having two CSS classes to distinguish between elements that have this *toggling* behaviour and elements that are primary (i.e. should be shown when their parent is clicked).

The markup:

```
<body>
  <p class="togglable">
    <div class="primary">
      This is the primary div that will be shown when our parent is clicked.
    </div>
    <div>Regular div child</div>
    <p>Nested paragraph</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A list perhaps</li>
    </ul>
  </p>

  <p class="togglable">
    <div class="primary">
      This is the primary div that will be shown when our parent is clicked.
    </div>
    <div>Regular div child</div>
    <p>Nested paragraph</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A list perhaps</li>
    </ul>
  </p>

  <p>This is a normal paragraph</p>
</body>
```

The code:

```
$(function () {
  $('.togglable').click(function () {
    // hide all our children
    $(this).children().hide();
    // now only show our primary chlid
    // NOTE: we pass 'this' as the second argument
    // so that the selector will only apply to the
    // children of the element that was clicked
    // (i.e. we are providing a custom context for the selector).
    $('.primary', this).show();     

    // You could even use the position of the child as well:
    // $(this).children().first().show();   
    // This will show the first child element.
  });
});
```

In this example all elements with the class `togglable` will show their primary child element when clicked and hide all other child elements.